# Genealogytree: "black" edges are not black

Tags: color, genealogytree

When using `genealogytree` I can change the color of the edges between nodes by passing a color name to `foreground` as in the following:

```
\gtrset{level size=8mm,node size=20mm}
\gtrset{edges={foreground=red,no background}}
\begin{genealogypicture}
  parent{
    g{Child}
    p{Parent}
    p{Parent}
  }
\end{genealogypicture}
```

[image: red edges]

However, when specifying `black` edges, the resulting color is not black but a dark green (same as the default color). This is easily seen with thicker edges:

```
\gtrset{level size=8mm,node size=20mm}
\gtrset{edges={foreground={line width=2mm,black},no background}}
\begin{genealogypicture}
  parent{
    g{Child}
    p{Parent}
    p{Parent}
  }
\end{genealogypicture}
```

[image: not black edges]

Why is this and how can I make the edges actually black?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen the manual but the colors are mostly either red or purple or green. You can use `\definecolor{black}{rgb}{0,0,0}` to have `black` color.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{genealogytree}

\definecolor{black}{rgb}{0,0,0}
\begin{document}
\gtrset{level size=8mm,node size=20mm}
\gtrset{edges={foreground={line width=2mm,black},no background}}
\begin{genealogypicture}
  parent{
    g{Child}
    p{Parent}
    p{Parent}
  }
\end{genealogypicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @AstianthusViminalis Please, can you see now? I hope that this times is black. 

Comment: After the edit: this works. For now I'll assume that `genealogytree` intentionally redefines or reinterprets `black` to be that default dark green color for whatever reason.

Comment: @AstianthusViminalis I'm glad that my code it works. I have read the manual https://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/genealogytree/genealogytree.pdf for saefty. I am not an expert, the package is probably set to have the lines with dark green. The important thing is that it works now. 

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you did not get black --the code worked correctly as below -- maybe some other line in your code -- the full document code has not been uploaded

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{genealogytree}

\begin{document}

\gtrset{level size=8mm,node size=20mm}
\gtrset{edges={foreground={line width=2mm,black},no background}}
\begin{genealogypicture}
    parent{
        g{Child}
        p{Parent}
        p{Parent}
    }
\end{genealogypicture}
\end{document}
```

Without the `\gtrset` included in the code I get-- the default settings--

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{genealogytree}

\begin{document}
\begin{genealogypicture}
    parent{
        g{Child}
        p{Parent}
        p{Parent}
    }
\end{genealogypicture}
\end{document}
```

Also, another way to make black blue whatever--

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{genealogytree}

\begin{document}
\newcommand{\mylist}{
    level distance=1cm,
    level 0/.style={node box={colback=red!50}},
    edges={no background,foreground={line width=2mm,black!70!green!70}},
}
\newcommand{\mylistt}{
    level distance=1cm,
    level 1/.style={node box={colback=red!50}},
    edges={no background,foreground={line width=2pt,yellow!50!red!80!black,Circle-Latex}},
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\genealogytree[keysfrom=\mylist
]{
    parent{
    g{Child}
    p{Parent}
    p{Parent}
}
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\genealogytree[keysfrom=\mylistt
]{
    parent{
        g{Child}
        p{Parent}
        p{Parent}
    }
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You're right, I should've sent a complete example document. However, when compiling even the one you sent which gave you black edges I _do_ get the dark green edges instead, so it's not something else in my code. Perhaps I'm using an old version of genealogytree? I'll see if I can update it.